# What's the best language to start write OS

Tags: operating-system

What's language is the more suitable to write the own OS like Windows but better only. Java or C#, or some else. And how many it will take days?
P. S. My friend asked me this question :)

Answer (score 2):

C is the best choice.

It will take you the rest of your days, and then some.

Comment: Thank you! The C is and forgot how this world looks :) Just it's a joke, guy! Just I don't wait so question from my friend (who is a programmer too)